# The number of imaginary roots of $\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac {n^2}{x-x_{n} }= 101$, where each $x_n$ is real

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

> Determine the number of imaginary roots of the equation
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac {n^2}{x-x_{n} }= 101$$
> where $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$, $\ldots$ are all real.

I did this question a few months back, but I am not able to do this question now.

Also, if anyone has seen this question before, please let me know its source.

Comment: Concepts upto class 12 level.

Comment: But what is "class 12 level"? Calculus, algebra 2, etc?

Comment: You can post any solution I would put all my effort and understand it eventually.

Comment: Yes..  @AndrewLi

Comment: By imaginary do you mean pure imaginary, or do you want the total number of non-real roots?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2585641/512534

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on the answer from @DavidK:

Let $x=a+bi$.

$$\frac1{x-x_n}=\frac1{a+x_n+bi}= \frac{a+x_n-bi}{(a+x_n)^2+b^2}= \frac{a+x_n}{(a+x_n)^2+b^2}+ \frac{-bi}{(a+x_n)^2+b^2}$$

So the imaginary part of the sum equals
$$b\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(a+x_n)^2+b^2}$$

Since $101$ is real, the above summation equals zero.

Observe that $$\frac{n^2}{(a+x_n)^2+b^2}>0$$

Can you see that $b=0$?

Comment: Yes.. Thanks everyone!! May God bless

Comment: @KavitaJuneja Would you like to accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is ambiguous about whether it asks for *purely* imaginary roots or merely for complex roots that are not real.
But let's take a look to see what kind of roots we can find.

Let $x$ be a complex number. Suppose the imaginary part of $x$ is positive.
For $n$ an integer and $x_n$ real,
what can you say about the imaginary part of
$$
\frac {n^2}{x-x_{n}}?
$$

Now add up a hundred terms in that form. What conditions will make the sum equal to $101$?

Comment: So no imaginary roots??

Comment: Neither purely imaginary nor any others that aren't real.

Comment: Thank you  sir.. :)